# Form Authentication, keep session Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, forms-authentication

I have a Google Apps script to communicate with an external program. The program wants an authentication to authenticate:

"The POST method should be used for this, and the content-type should be set to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". The user name should be given in parameter "*UserName*" and the password should be given in parameter "*Password*". So the post data will be something like "*UserName*=xxx&*Password*=yyy". Keep in mind that when not sending the user name and password each request, that the session (or the object that keeps it) should be kept alive."

This is working:

```
 var payload = "_UserName_="+username+"&_Password_="+password
 var options = {
 "method" : "POST",
 "payload" : payload,
 "contentType" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
};

 var xml = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://start.application.nl/docs/XMLDivisions.aspx",        options);
```

But here I want to make the next request:

```
  var xml = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://start.application.nl/docs/XMLDownload.aspx?PartnerKey="+partnerKey+"&Topic=Accounts");
```

but not authenticated?

How can I keep a GAS session alive?

A working example using PHP:

```
    <?php
$baseurl = "https://start.exactonline.nl";
$username = "<username>";
$password = "<password>";
$partnerkey = ""; /* If you have one, the partnerkey with or without curly braces */
$division = "<division code>";  /* Check the result of the first division retrieving for the division codes */
$cookiefile = "cookie.txt";
$crtbundlefile = "cacert.pem"; /* this can be downloaded from http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html */


/* Logging in */
$header[1] = "Cache-Control: private";
$header[2] = "Connection: Keep-Alive";

/* init, don't term until you're completely done with this session */
$ch = curl_init();

/* Set all options */
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookiefile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $crtbundlefile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array("_UserName_"=>"$username", "_Password_"=>"$password"));

/* Retrieving divisions, the current should be the one in which the user worked the last time */
$url = "$baseurl/docs/XMLDivisions.aspx";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$result = curl_exec($ch);

/* Switching divisions */
$url = "$baseurl/docs/ClearSession.aspx?Division=$division&Remember=3";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$result = curl_exec($ch);

/* Retrieving divisions, the current should now be the one supplied in the switching divisions. This is only the current for this session! */
$url = "$baseurl/docs/XMLDivisions.aspx";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$result = curl_exec($ch);

/* Upload an xml file */
$topic = "Invoices";
$url = "$baseurl/docs/XMLUpload.aspx?Topic=$topic&PartnerKey=$partnerkey";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
/* Send the xml along with the request */
$filename = "Invoices.xml";
$fp = fopen($filename, "r");
$xml = fread($fp, filesize($filename));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, utf8_encode($xml));
$result = curl_exec($ch);

/* Finally close as we're finished with this session */
curl_close($ch);

echo $result;
?>
```

Comment: is there any reason not to resend the payload for the second call?

Comment: Yes, this is a call to XMLDownload for getting the data.
The payload needs to be set to XML data when I want to post something. 

When I add the payload together with the call, it is allright, but I cannot send a x-www-form-urlencoded for auth AND application/xml at the same time?

Comment: This is how it is done with PHP:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are missing the cookie.

Try something like this:

```
var payload = "_UserName_="+username+"&_Password_="+password
 var options = {
 "method" : "POST",
 "payload" : payload,
 "contentType" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
};

 var xml = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://start.application.nl/docs/XMLDivisions.aspx",        options);

var cookie = response.getAllHeaders()['Set-Cookie'];
```

Then, send the cookie in the second request **along your other prepared headers.**

```
var header = {'Cookie':cookie};
var opt = {"headers":header};

var xml = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://start.application.nl/docs/XMLDownload.aspx?PartnerKey="+partnerKey+"&Topic=Accounts",opts);
```

I think that should work, but sometimes the server needs not only the session in the cookie, but also the same IP address should make the request, in that case google IP's sometimes change...

Comment: It seems to me like HttpOnly cookies are also not returned, which are likely to be those useful for authentication.