# How to direct Puppeteer downloads directly into Google AppScript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api, puppeteer, google-sheets-api

would appreciate if anyone can suggest ideas:

I currently have a Puppeteer script which automates CSV downloads into google drive which then allows me to programmatically access the data and move it into google sheets.

Currently, I run this locally on my computer on VS code. I don't yet understand all too well how to handle file downloads through puppeteer, but I currently have a work around by setting the default chrome download path to a folder on my computer, and that folder is actually Drive for desktop, so easy way to get files directly in drive.

```
await page._client.send('Page.setDownloadBehavior', {behavior: 'allow', downloadPath: path.resolve('G:/My Drive/DriveData')});
```

Thing is, I'd like this to be some type of scheduled cloud function not having to be manually run on my computer. IF I were to do that, my Drive for Desktop work-around would not be viable. So is there a way I could pass the file download in Puppeteer directly into Google AppScript somehow? Or use the Drive API to directly receive the file?

My main issue is I don't understand how to actually handle file downloads in Puppeteer, I'm currently just editing the default download location for the google chrome instance puppeteer creates. I ultimately just need to get the data somewhere accessible by Google AppScript.

Any suggestions would be uber-appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same situation, unfortunately we cant install or use puppeteer in google app script environment,
The alternative is to do the file download using UrlFetchApp , cookies and sessions 
[using session and cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15414864/form-authentication-keep-session-google-apps-script)

The following code will help you save the file into Gdrive

```
var file = folder.createFile(UrlFetchApp.fetch("url of the downloaded file fetched dynamically"));
```

You need to check through the network logs in chrome to know how the file and on what URL request you are getting the file downloaded which you can pass to the function

 Another alternative that will help you to download the file to drive is to use https://developers.google.com/drive
I had used python to save files in drive https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/using-google-drive--api-in-python